# Regular expression not capturing the whole value in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract the action values

```
action="/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOKd3R09TMx9DAz8TT1dDDxdnDzMTZwtjQ18TYEKIoEKDHAARwNC-sP1o_Aq8TSHKsBjhZ9Hfm6qfkFuhEGWiaMiALSXEgg!/pw/Z7_CGAH47L00O5ID0IDBH74C930E2/act/id=0/p=action=wps.portlets.login/222093291909/=/#Z7_CGAH47L00O5ID0IDBH74C930E2"
```

Regular expression used:-

```
action="(.+?)"
```

It is returning only the value as:

```
"/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOKd3R09TMx9DAz8TT1dDDxdnDzMTZwtjQ18TYEKIoEKDHAARwNC-sP1o_Aq8TSHKsBjhZ9Hfm6qfkFuhEGWiaMiALSXEgg!/pw/Z7_CGAH47L00O5ID0IDBH74C930E2/act/id=0/p=action=wps.portlets.login/222001304055/=/"
```

`#Z7_CGAH47L00O5ID0IDBH74C930E2` is missing in the extracted value

Comment: In what language are you doing the regex and what is the piece of code are you using?

Comment: I am using the Regular expression extractor in JMeter. 
Regular Expression:- action="(.+?)"
Template:- $1$
Match No:- 1

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer....Actually I was doing it in a wrong way.
action="([^"]+)# solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

have you tryed:

```
action="([^"]+)"
```

Comment: Yes, I did tried that as well but it was giving the same result